# SAMBA: user root does not exist

Tags: samba, ldap

I'm following the [UBUNTU server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-ldap.html) to install and configure SAMBA:

Everything went exactly as mentioned, except when I try to samba LDAP objects by

```
smbldap-populate
```

I get the error:

```
Please provide a password for the domain root:
/usr/sbin/smbldap-passwd: user root doesn't exist
```

Can anyone help me to sort this out? Please explain your solution briefly.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I tried to modify the /etc/smbldap-tools/smbldap_bind.conf file

```
slaveDN="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=local"
slavePw="passwd"
masterDN="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=local"
masterPw="passwd"
```

and gave the same password to the LDAP tree:

```
smbpasswd -w passwd
```

(passwd is the same password I gave when installing LDAP)

Now I get the following error when I run `smbldap-populate`

```
entry dc=example,dc=com already exist.
entry ou=People,dc=example,dc=com already exist.
entry ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com already exist.
entry ou=Machines,dc=example,dc=com already exist.
entry ou=Idmap,dc=example,dc=com already exist.
entry sambaDomainName=EXAMPLE.COM,dc=example,dc=com already exist. Updating it...

failed to modify entry: modifications require authentication at /usr/sbin/smbldap-populate line 493.
entry uid=root,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com already exist.
entry uid=nobody,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com already exist.
entry cn=Domain Admins,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com already exist.
entry cn=Domain Users,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com already exist.
entry cn=Domain Guests,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com already exist.
entry cn=Domain Computers,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com already exist.
entry cn=Administrators,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com already exist.
entry cn=Account Operators,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com already exist.
entry cn=Print Operators,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com already exist.
entry cn=Backup Operators,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com already exist.
entry cn=Replicators,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com already exist.

Please provide a password for the domain root:
Changing UNIX and samba passwords for root
New password:
Retype new password:
Use of uninitialized value in exec at /usr/sbin/smbldap-passwd line 192, <STDIN> line 2.
Can't exec "": No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/smbldap-passwd line 192, <STDIN> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $smbldap_tools::config{"slappasswd"} in string at /usr/share/perl5/smbldap_tools.pm line 1541, <STDIN> line 2.
Can't exec "": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/smbldap_tools.pm line 1541, <STDIN> line 2.
readline() on closed filehandle BUF at /usr/share/perl5/smbldap_tools.pm line 1545.
Failed to generate password hash!
Failed to generate password hash!
```

Comment: did you do : `sudo systemctl restart smbd.service nmbd.service` ?

Comment: I tried 
          `service smbd nmbd restart`
and tried again, but get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, solved this.
It's a problem with smbldap.conf and smbldap_bind.conf files. For some reason the user credentials in them did not match the ones I entered.

Running `smbldap-config` and rebuilding the above files lets you reset these information.